# fast way to replace characters in file ignoring comment lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How can I replace/delete characters in a file while leaving comment lines unchanged? I'm looking for a something to the effect of the following lines (where 'X' is replaced for 'Y' in file.txt), just *substantially faster*:

```
while read line
do  
  if [[ ${line:0:1} = "#" ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
  else
    echo "$line" | tr "X" "Y"
  fi
done < file.txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent, more accurate (and faster) will be this sed command as compared to your script:

```
sed '/^ *#/!{s/X/Y/g;}' file.txt
```

This means match any line that doesn't have `0 or more spaces followed by #` at the start of line and replace X with Y globally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's about 30 times faster than the read line construct in my case.

Answer (score 1):

i am willing to bet perl will be faster than all above :

```
 perl -i -pe 's/X/Y/g unless /^#/' file.txt
```

Comment: In my tests it was approximately as fast as the sed replacement, but not significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

for fast replacement, use `sed`, and only replace in lines *not* starting with "#":

```
 cat foo.txt | sed -e '/^#/! s/X/Y/g'
```

Comment: [Useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat); useless use of `-e`.

Comment: What if commented line has few leading spaces before `#` ?

Comment: @devnull in examples i prefer *useless use of cat* as it shows better how to insert the code into a chain of pipes. if the data is really residing in a file and `sed` is really the only filter that has to be applied, then you obviously ought to give the file to `sed`. i don't see any harm with a useless `-e`

Comment: In examples, you prefer to introduce newbies to options that are *irrelevant*?  In example, you prefer to add `|` by introducing UUOC thereby making those appear more complex?

Comment: @l0b0: I know that (and have used that in my answer submitted 2 mins before this answer). I was pointing it to this specific answer since this doesn't address that.

Comment: @devnull: Totally agree with useless use of cat here since OP is also trying to work on a file directly `file.txt`.

Comment: `-1` for UUOC and `-e` and that extra `|` that came with UUOC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's about 30 times faster than the read line construct in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/^#/! s/{what_to_replace}/{to_what_to_replace}/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` version:

```
awk '!/^ *#/{gsub(/X/,"Y")}1' file.txt
```

Do look for word boundaries to prevent sub strings of your substitution from getting replaced. For example, with `gawk` you can use `\<` and `\>`

Comment: Thank you, but in my case (deleting two characters from a commented file) your awk solution takes even longer than the read line script;  the sed-based solution is at least 50 times faster!